# Application insights SDK - Map inter-resource dependencies

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm trying to create an end-to-end Application Map using Application Insights. Note all dependencies and metrics are captured and sent using the SDK.

Take the following scenario:
Windows service (batch processing) > (calls) WebAPI > (queries db)

I have 2 Application Insight resources - Windows Service and WebAPI. Both are capturing metrics but in isolation. How can I create a dependency using the SDK between resource 1 (i.e. service) and resource 2 (i.e. WebAPI)?  I need to be able to view the Application Map for resource 1 and be able to see the entire end-to-end view of windows service > web service > db.

I can currently see only windows service > WebApi (App Map resource 1) or WebApi > db (App Map resource 2). Need to bring both together somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Insights sdk only collect dependencies automatically for HTTP dependencies. Also it only works when the application insights profiler is running on the machine (often installed on azure websites through the Application Insights Extension).

If you happen to be in one of the situations where the new beta sdk is not collecting dependencies for you. You can do that on your own by writing a little bit of code yourself.

The sdk's autocollection code is open source and you can use it to guide you as to how to track these dependencies. The idea is to append the dependency telemetry's target field with the hash of the target component's instrumentation key and set the dependency type to "Application Insights".

Here is how to compute the hash: [Compute Hash](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/8c51d66c08c1baf0844613637fa5d3ccfc7590f9/Src/Common/InstrumentationKeyHashLookupHelper.cs#L56-L65)

Here is how to add it to the target field and set the right dependency type on the dependency telemetry object: [Add component correlation to DependencyTelemetryTarget](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/c83568ba98134194ac8efe6bedf3bdf3f5fa13c5/Src/DependencyCollector/Shared/Implementation/ProfilerHttpProcessing.cs#L388-L395)

A little word of caution. There may soon be a change to the format in which the target field is captured / the name of the dependency type (see [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/323)). If and when that happens, it would be an easy enough change for you too.

Comment: Actually, you should also set the source property on your RequestTelemetry objects for incoming requests. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/71aee35b7cf68aa2e10358081aa9421c7dcc8a6f/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer.cs#L91-L105) is how you do that.

Comment: Nizar - thank you, that's exactly what I was missing.  I'll keep updated with the ongoing discussions regarding the dependency type name. For now, it's working as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use the same Application Insights resources (e.g. instrumentation key) for both your Windows Service and Web API.
You can separate your telemetry for those two services by adding a custom property indicating the service for all telemetry you emit. Easiest way to do this would be to implement a telemetry initializer (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties) for documentation).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible today. Possible ways -

- Use a single InstrumentationKey and identify by a custom property (as
  suggested by @[EranG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7408508/erang)
- Export the data for both the apps and do your own thing

Please vote on this [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/15165558-support-for-cross-ikey-cross-application-queries). Product team is already considering implementing this functionality in future.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm trying to use such a feature in the latest 2.3.0 beta release of AI, which supports this feature - see [https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/app-insights-app-map-preview.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/app-insights-app-map-preview.md). This shows links between resources, just doesn't detail much information of how to achieve this via the SDK.

Comment: Are you viewing your application map using the link provided in the preview announcement?

Comment: Yes. Just can't find which properties need to be set on the DependencyTelemetry/RequestTelemetry to wire up the 2 resources.